# Traveling without an ID

Tags: paperwork, buses, new-york-city, road-trips

I turned 18 on August 23rd, and have not been able to obtain a photo ID yet. The DMV's have been closed because of COVID. The one that I need to go to in my area is one of the few that's open, so it's impossible to get in. I got in like at 4:00 in the morning, and waited for hours, and they still couldn't get me in. I am trying to go from Chicago IL to Cobleskill NY. I don't want to fly, and I'd prefer to take an overnight bus because it's cheaper and more accessible. Does anyone know a way for me to be able to travel via overnight bus without an ID?